# How to swap elements on 2D array functional way in JAVA

Tags: java, declarative

I'm trying to refactor imperative transpose function to declarative one. Here is the imperative implementation:

```
for (int i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < routes.length; j++) {
            Route temp = routes[j][i];
            routes[j][i] = routes[i][j];
            routes[i][j] = temp;
        }
    }
```

And here is my desperate attempt which stuck due to cognitive load:

```
Arrays.stream(routes).forEach(routes1 -> Arrays.stream(routes1).forEach(
            route -> {
                Route temp ??
            }
    ));
```

I guess solution lies in the using map instead forEach but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
int[][] routes = {{1, 2, 3},
                  {4, 5, 6},
                  {7, 8, 9}};

// convert columns to rows
Map<Integer, List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>>> rows = Arrays.stream(routes)
        .flatMap(ints -> IntStream.range(0, ints.length).mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i, ints[i])))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey));

// extract values from rows
Integer[][] result = rows.values().stream().map(simpleEntries -> simpleEntries.stream()
        .map(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue).toArray(Integer[]::new))
        .toArray(Integer[][]::new);
```

**Output**

```
1 4 7 
2 5 8 
3 6 9
```

You could think of transposing a matrix as converting columns to rows, that is the basic idea here. In the first map we group values by the column index, this are going to be the new rows, the second part just extracts the values from the `Map`.